# Get lint warnings and errors within a given file

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I'd like to run lint for the whole project. But what I want is the warnings and errors within a given file.

Is there any way to do this in Android Studio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean Analyze->Inspect Code ... ?

Comment: Yes. For example, I run lint for the whole project, but I only want to see the warning and errors in a certain file, say MyActivity.java. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: By the way, is there any difference for a certain file, say MyActivity.java,  between running lint in the whole project mode and only in that file mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file and then press `Command + Shift + A` which will open `Enter action or option name. Type`Inspect Code` and hit enter. There you can specify to only inspect against a certain single file.